# User behaviour tracking in JavaScript

Tags: javascript, user-tracking

I need to track the user's behaviour throughout a web page, for example: where he has clicked, in what order he has filled the textboxes, what he have written (and how much time he needed to write that), if he has scrolled the page, if the page has lost focus (for example by opening a new tab).
Is there a javascript framework/library that does this work? And, moreover, can this fw send the collected data via JSON?

Comment: I need something like ClickTale, but stand-alone, in order to use it in a custom web app I'm already developing.

Answer (score 1):

There are 3rd party scripts available for tracking user behavior, yes. For example, Google Analytics, Piwik and Adobe Analytics.  All of them will give you basic info out-of-the-box (e.g. visits, visitors, page views, time on page, entry/exit pages, etc..) but in order to get a lot of what you're asking for, it's going to require custom implementation on your end.

I would also suggest you re-evaluate some of those things you want to track. I can tell you from experience (I work in the Web Analytics industry) that nobody really tracks most of that stuff, since there's very little action/decision making you can actually make from those things.

Comment: It's a very particular application that will run on intranet networks.
I already know the possibilities of Google Analytics (such as Async Tracking), but unfortunately I cannot rely on external services (because as I said is an intranet application) and I need to do all the stuff internally.

Comment: Okay well then I suggest you look into Piwik, since you install that on your own server.

Comment: But Piwik offers only "standard" tracking, not behaviour tracking.

Comment: there is no solution out there that offers behavior tracking out-of-the-box, because websites are uniquely coded. But they all offer a way to implement behavior tracking, by populating certain variables within their library. Many of them even offer plugins that help out. But you will have to do some custom coding on your end to pop those variables, there's no way around that, because all websites are uniquely coded; no one-size-fits-all magic wand :(